# Web service time out problem

Tags: .net, web-services

have a data transfer between an vb application and web service. The
application is in local network and connects to the internet thru a
gateway. Connection is ADSL.
Web service is on the remote server.
  Strange thing is that data transfer sometimes work and sometimes not.
When it doesn't work, it throws an exception of type
'System.Net.WebException' and message is 'The operation has timed-out'.
And it doesn't depend on amount of data.And also sometimes it raises error like connection terminated.When i restart my test server,problem gones away but what can cause it?Test server's firewall is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The ADSL is not the problem, I do that alot.
you need to make some more tests to rule out several options:
once you get a timeout - issue another call from another process - see if the timeout stays until you restart the server.
put debug lines to console - about the call (before invoke, during the operation, and after invoke) - to see where it hangs.

see if you can trace the actual message from the moment it reaches the server until it lefts is (like in wcf tracing options)

this should reveal the position that the call might be stuck.

sometimes a malformed data that should be returned might casue this behaviour, or even a cyclic reference in the data.